# Access CustomAttribute in the view page in mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, custom-attributes

I have created a custom attribute 'RoleAction' and added to the model property

```
public class RoleActionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string UserRole { get; set; }

    public RoleActionAttribute(string Role)
    {
        this.UserRole = Role;
    }

}


[RoleAction("Manager")] 
public EmployeeName
```

How to I get the RoleAction value (Manager) in my mvc view page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Reflection in order to fetch custom attributes:

```
var roleAction = (RoleActionAttribute)typeof(MyViewModel)
    .GetProperty("EmployeeName")
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RoleActionAttribute), true)
    .FirstOrDefault();
if (roleAction != null)
{
    var role = roleAction.UserRole;
}
```

Another possibility is to use Metadata and make your custom attribute metadata aware by implementing the new [IMetadataAware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imetadataaware.aspx) interface that was introduced in ASP.NET MVC 3:

```
public class RoleActionAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    public string UserRole { get; set; }

    public RoleActionAttribute(string Role)
    {
        this.UserRole = Role;
    }

    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AdditionalValues["role"] = UserRole;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
var metaData = ModelMetadataProviders
    .Current
    .GetMetadataForProperty(null, typeof(MyViewModel), "EmployeeName");
if (metaData != null)
{
    string userRole = metaData.AdditionalValues["role"] as string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitrov.. I was hoping for a more elegant solution.. My situation is I have a bunch of properties in my model and they are editable in the view page if the user belongs to certain roles which I have access to in the view page. I found this link which talks about AdditionalMetadata which is unknow type in my code not matter what i do http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2011/01/30/mvc-3-additionalmetadata-attribute-with-viewbag-to-render-dynamic-ui.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TempData` for it.